# Why Bosh lite eating up disk space even it's not in use?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am using bosh-lite to play with cloudfoudry, after installed cloud foundry, I haven't deployed any apps, but I left the virtualbox machine up for two days, I found out now all of my disk spaces(8G left before) was used.

Want to understand why bosh-lite/cloud foundry use so much disk space, is it because of the logging persisted somewhere? how can I release these space?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the content of /var/vcap/sys/log on each machine, but better to redeploy CF with proper logging options set to external syslog per https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/running/managing-cf/logging.html (Log Forwarding)